# can someone explain this equation to me from the c program about generating prime number till 100

Tags: arrays, c, primes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int p;
    int i;
    int j;

    int primes[50] = {0};
    int primeIndex = 2;

    bool isPrime;

    // hardcode prime numbers
    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;

    for(p = 5; p <= 100; p = p + 2)
    {
        isPrime = true;


        for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
            if (p % primes[i] == 0)
                isPrime = false;



        if (isPrime == true)
        {
            primes[primeIndex] = p;
            ++primeIndex;
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0;  i < primeIndex;  ++i )
         printf ("%i  ", primes[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

explain ths eqution from above program

```
        for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
            if (p % primes[i] == 0)
                isPrime = false;
```

the code works fine it about generating prime number till 100 and storing in arry and then displaying it but I didnt understand it's logic ples explain it to me

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: At first I'd consider it bad code – the value `isPrime` is checked again and again separately within every loop run and we'd rely on an optimiser to eliminate it again. Better would have been: `for(i = 1; p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i) { if(...) { isPrime = false; break; } }`. At the same time only the relevant check remains in the loop header. Then I *personally* think it would have been better written as `primes[i]*primes[i] <= p`, this shows more obviously the actual intention: Only iterate as long as the prime numbers found so far are smaller or equal to the square root of `p`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is *not* the sieve of Erathosthenes here! Though it would have been more efficient (unless there wasn't enough memory available for...).

Comment: Side note: My *'more obvious'* variant still has a drawback, though: for integers `p` close to `INT_MAX` the larger squares might already *overflow*! The variant given originally doesn't have this problem, but in the range we're iterating this isn't of any relevance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It checks if the number has been found not prime until now. Then it checks if the number is bigger than the square root of the next prime to check. If the number can be divided by that prime, then it isn't prime. If not, it will check the next one and so on. After the for loop, if isPrime variable is still true, then the number is prime and will be added to the array.